# Why does sudoers.d ignore filenames with dots in them?

Tags: sudo, sudoers

by default sudo parse config files in `/etc/sudoers.d/*` whose filename does not contain `.` and `~` , meaning `user.conf` is ignored and `user_conf` is parsed.

Why does /etc/sudoers.d ignore files with dots in them? Seems like a strange decision, sure to bite many sysadmins? I just wasted many minutes figuring out why directives in

```
/etc/sudoers.d/hans.conf
```

did not work~

Answer (score 4):

From [`man 5 sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers) [emphasis mine]:

> The `@includedir` directive can be used to create a `sudoers.d` directory that the system package manager can drop sudoers file rules into as part of package installation. For example, given:
>
> ```
> @includedir /etc/sudoers.d
> ```
>
> `sudo` will suspend processing of the current file and read each file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, skipping file names that end in `~` or contain a `.` character **to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files**.

Answer (score 2):

It's an attempt to generically ignore all possible "backup" files that package managers may leave. For example, if `/etc/sudoers.d/foo` is or has been distributed as part of a package, then you might at some point have `foo.dpkg-new` or `foo.rpmold` or `foo.pacsave` or `foo.ucf-new`, none of which are supposed to be "active" (either they belong to a package that has been removed, or they're new versions that are to be installed).

Other tools usually choose to require a specific suffix (e.g. only accepting `*.conf` and ignoring the rest); sudo instead chose to reject any file name with a suffix.